# Locale dependent regexp in Angular application (dot or coma for decimals)

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have Angular 2 + PrimeNG application which uses regexp for numbers with floating point:

```
<input pInputText pattern="[0-9]*\.[0-9]" [(ngModel)]="someModel"/>
```

It works well for US locale, however some of countries use coma for decimals so the pattern is not suitable for them.

Currently I'm thinking of retrieving separator inside component code and dynamically constructing the regexp there.

**Q:** How to handle locale dependent regexps and what is the best/canonical way of doing that?

Note: I need this to work only in Chrome and I need to take into account only browser locale. I'm using `browser-locale 1.0.2` for output.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. Is it to match strings with dot AND coma ? Or match dot OR coma depending on current locale defined ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this post here is my solution:

You can get the locale by injecting LOCALE_ID.
Based on this you can use

```
getLocaleNumberSymbol(locale: string, symbol: NumberSymbol): string
```

from @angular/common ([doku](https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleNumberSymbol))

With this I created a service that localizes my patterns. The patterns are stored in the enum ValidationExpression.

Service:

```
import { getLocaleNumberSymbol, NumberSymbol } from "@angular/common";
import { Inject, Injectable, LOCALE_ID } from "@angular/core";
import { ValidationExpression } from "./validation-expression.enum";
...
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string) {
}

public getLocalizedPattern(expression: ValidationExpression): string {
    const separator = getLocaleNumberSymbol(this._locale, NumberSymbol.Decimal);
    return expression.replace("delimiter", "\\" + separator);
}
```

Pattern enum:

```
export enum ValidationExpression {
   decimal = "^(\\-|\\+)?([0-9]+((delimiter)[0-9]+)?)$",
   decimalPos = "^[+]?([1-9][0-9]*(?:[delimiter][0-9]*)?|0*[delimiter]0*[1-9][0-9]*)$",
   decimalPosWithZero = "^(\\+)?([0-9]+((delimiter)[0-9]+)?)$",
   int = "^(\\-|\\+)?[0-9]+$",
   intPos = "^\\+?[1-9]\\d*$",
   intPosWithZero = "^\\+?[0-9]\\d*$"
}
```

Note that my patterns don't include the thousands separator (1,234.56)

Comment: Instead of injecting LOCALE_ID you also can use your `browser-locale`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match strings with comma or dot

```
[0-9]*'[\.,][0-9]
```

https://regex101.com/r/hFnzW0/1

If you want to match either dot or comma depending on user's defined locales, use either `[0-9]*'[\.][0-9]` to match dots, `[0-9]*'[,][0-9]` to match commas

**EDIT**

I've found this :

```
<label for="regex">Set a pattern (regex string): </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="regex" id="regex" />

<label for="input">This input is restricted by the current pattern: </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="regex" /><br>
```

With this you could define the regex depending on your locales in `#regex` and use it for your 200 other inputs. This way you define it only once.

Comment: Yes, I need to match either dot or comma depending on locale and it is clear that I have to use different patterns depending on locale. But the question is how to do that?

Comment: See my edit, might not be the best solution but it can lead you to it

Comment: Unfortunately it is not an option. I need generic solution, this one will require  `switch` with 200 options :)

Comment: Googled a little for you, see my new edit (finger crossed)

Comment: I faced this issue and your solution isn't good, because american use dots and commas (like 192.397,22). This means the regex you gave isn't able to handle that.

Comment: The thing is that he only want the first number after the dot/comma `\.[0-9]` so it doesn't matter here.